# Can i save the output of a joined table into another table?

Tags: sqlite

I created a database and having two tables like x and y. I cross joined them both and got an output.Now my question is can i save that output to a new table in the same database or different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you can try running the query `SELECT * FROM table1 CROSS JOIN table2`.  Observe what columns are returned from the query, then create a new table `new_table` with columns of the appropriate type.  Then you can try using `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO new_table
SELECT * FROM table1 CROSS JOIN table2;
```

Comment: we cannot create an empty table with diff columns right?new_table with what parameters inside?
ex: CREATE TABLE CROSSJOINED(whats parameters i have to put here?);

Comment: Execute the `CROSS JOIN` and see which columns you are returned.  Then do a `CREATE TABLE` with the appropriate number of columns and types.

Answer (score 0):

The [CREATE TABLE statement](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) directly accepts a query:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table AS
SELECT * FROM table1 CROSS JOIN table2;
```

(This will not keep the column types.)

The output can be saved in a different database if that database has been [ATTACH](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html)ed.